# Sumar y tomar el numero mas cercano a un valor

Tags: javascript

Recientemente estoy haciendo practicas en javascript, la practica consiste en se te da un valor, en este caso 15 y debes sumar 2 propiedades de un array de números que den igual o mas cercanos al valor buscado osea 15, lo que esto debe retornas es el indice de los numeros usados para obtener el valor

```
    const time = 15;

const courses = [2, 3, 8, 1, 4];


function learn( ) {


 
for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
  
    for (let e = 1; e < courses.length; e++){
        if(courses[i] + courses[e] ===  time){
          const result =  [courses.indexOf(courses[i]), courses.indexOf(courses[e])]
           
            return result
            
        } 
    }
  
}


  
}
```

he logrado obtener el indice de los números usados para obtener el resultado, cuando el valor que busco se encuentra sumando los valores del array, pero no se para que me de un valor cercano a 15,  en este caso quisiera que retornara la posición 0 y 4 [8,4] cuya suma es 12

Comment: Buen día, una pregunta ¿Los números en tu lista, se pueden utilizar más de una vez? Con tu código si pongo 16 sale `[2, 2]` como resultado ¿Es esto correcto? ¿O los números se pueden utilizar una sola vez?

Comment: Solo se pueden usar una vez, por ejemplo si yo pongo 16, me sale null, por eso en el segundo for declare e = 1, para comenzar por el siguiente elemento a 0, en este caso comenzaría a sumar  2[0] y 3[1]

Comment: Copié y pegué tu código y el resultado que devuelve es `[2, 2]` ¿Si sale `null` tal vez no pusiste la última versión de tu código?

Comment: segundo for declare e = 1, para comenzar por el siguiente elemento a 0, en este caso comenzaría a sumar 2[0] y 3[1]

Comment: @HeytalePazguato ahi peque el codigo nuevamente

Comment: Así es, pero 16 serían 2 veces 8 que es el índice 2 y tus dos `for` lo toman en cuenta, pruébalo

Comment: si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function encontrarParMasCercano(arr, x){
    //dif es la diferencia mínima que encontramos
    let dif = null
    //res_izq y res_der son los índices de los resultados
    let res_izq = 0
    let res_der = 0
    //inizializamos izq a la izquierda del arreglo y der a la derecha del arreglo
    let izq = 0
    let der = arr.length - 1

    //Mientras los punteros no se hayan "encontrado"
    while (izq < der){
        //Calculamos la diferencia entre la suma de este par y el número objetivo
        const nuevaDif = Math.abs(arr[izq] + arr[der] - x)
        //Si este par está más cerca de x que el mejor par encontrado anteriormente actualizamos res_izq, res_der y la diferencia mínima
        if (dif === null || nuevaDif < dif){
            res_izq = izq
            res_der = der
            dif = nuevaDif
        }

        // Si la suma de este par es más que x, nos movemos hacia el lado menor
        if (arr[izq] + arr[der] > x)
            der--;
        else //Si no, nos movemos hacia el lado mayor 
            izq++;
    }

    //Retornamos los índices hallados
    return [res_izq, res_der]
}

let arr = [2, 3, 8, 1, 4]

//Para que este método funcione, el arreglo debe estar ordenado de forma ascendente:
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)

const res = encontrarParMasCercano(arr, 15)
console.log(`Los índices hallados son: ${res}\n${arr[res[0]]} + ${arr[res[1]]} = ${arr[res[0]] + arr[res[1]]}`)
```

Si quieres obtener los indices en el arreglo original puedes hacer:

```
let arr = [2, 3, 8, 1, 4]
let arr2 = [...arr]

//Para que este método funcione, el arreglo debe estar ordenado de forma ascendente:
arr2.sort((a, b) => a - b)

const res = encontrarParMasCercano(arr2, 10)
const res_arreglo_original = [arr.indexOf(arr2[res[0]]), arr.indexOf(arr2[res[1]])]

console.log(res_arreglo_original)
```

Comment: Buen día, la respuesta devuelve los índices 3 y 4, es decir los números 1 y 4 por lo que no funcionaría de forma correcta. eso es porque ordenas el arreglo y los índices cambian, pero no sabemos si el OP debe mostrar los índices tal cual están a la entrada o si puede modificarlos

Comment: @HeytalePazguato, sí porque como aclare en el código el arreglo debe estar ordenado. Habría que usar un `indexOf` si sq quiere obtener el índice en el arreglo original. La ventaja de que esté ordenado es que hallar cada par solo requiere, como máximo, `n - 1` comparaciones. Tu respuesta requiere, como máximo, `n^2 - n` comparaciones. Dependiendo de cuántos pares quieras hallar conviene usar una u otra solución.

Comment: Así es, la situación que no sabemos (Hasta que el OP lo aclare) es si se puede modificar el orden del arreglo, si tiene que devolver el índice según el orden original entonces la solución no sería válida. De igual forma tenemos que esperar que el OP aclare y vea las soluciones

Comment: Entendible. De todos modos sostengo firmemente que mi solución es mejor para arreglos grandes o para hallar muchos pares. La complejidad de ordenar y hallar un par es `(n log n) + n - 1` . Esto es generalmente mejor que `n² - n`. Pero si quieres modifico la respuesta para que retorne los indices en el arreglo original.

Comment: Si, el número de iteraciones es menor, lo que haría falta es devolver el índice original (Que también podrías agregarlo a tu respuesta para completarla)

Comment: Esta forma de hacerlo luego la analizare para entenderla también, muchas gracias por ayudarme (:

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Para evaluar que los índices de la suma no se repitan puedes utilizar `continue` adentro del segundo `for` eso evitará obtener 2 veces el mismo índice

Para obtener el resultado más cercano podrías evaluar si `time` restando la suma de los dos números es el menor valor posible

Ejemplo:

```js
let  time = 10;
let courses = [2, 3, 8, 1, 4];
function learn( ) {
    // Creamos una variable para sumar los índices
    let sum = null;
  // Creamos una variable para guardar el resultado de los índices
  let result = null;
  // Recorremos el arreglo courses para evaluar todos los valores
    for (let i in courses){
    for (let j in courses){
        // Si el índice i y j son iguales entonces ignoramos y continuamos con la siguiente iteración
        if (i == j){
        continue;
      }
      // En caso de que i y j no sean iguales entonces evaluamos los valores
      else {
        // Creamos una variable temporal que sume los valores en los índices i y j
        let temp = (courses[i] + courses[j])
        // Revisamos si sum es null o si time - la suma de los valores es menor a time - el valor actual de sum
        if ((sum == null) || ((time - temp) < (time - sum))){
            // Evaluamos si la suma de los índices es mayora al valor deseado (time), si es así, ignoramos estos índices
            if (temp > time) {
            continue;
          }
          // Actualizamos el valor de sum y obtenemos los índices que proporcionan el valor más cercano en la iteración actual
          else {
            sum = (temp);
            result = [i, j];
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  // Devolvemos el valor de los índices al final de los ciclos for con los valores de i y j que sumados son igual o el valor más cercano a time
  return result;
}
console.log(learn())
```

**Edición** Tenía un error en el código y siempre devolvía 2 y 4, lo he corregido

En JavaScript tienes varios tipos de ciclos `for` puedes revisar como funcionan en [esta página](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_forin.asp)

Comment: probé el codigo, pero si cambio el time a 10, me da [2,4] en vez de darme [0,2] ):

Comment: @Graziel,  Como agregué en la edición, hice un cambio porque siempre devolvía 2 y 4, prueba con este código

Comment: Si esta perfecto muchas gracias, ahora lo analizare para comprenderlo

Comment: una pregunta, por que al poner los índices i y j  no se declaran primero? osea i = 0 y j = 0 y el i++ y el j++? osea lo tipico del ciclo for

Comment: Agregué comentarios al ejemplo para que puedas entenderlo mejor. En JavaScript tienes varios tipos de ciclos `for` uno de ellos es `for/in` que en este caso recorre cada elemento del arreglo. Puse la referencia en la respuesta para que puedas estudiarlo

Comment: vale muchas gracias

Comment: Si algo no está claro avísame y edito la respuesta para aclararlo

Comment: asi lo hare, muchas gracias

Comment: tengo una duda por que al final sum = (temp) pro que temp dentro de paréntesis?

Comment: Ah, no los necesita jaja, se me pasó al probar el código, es que antes tenía la suma de valores directamente en esa línea pero luego declaré `temp`

Comment: Creo que ya entendi tu logica, pusiste a restar el valor requerido  con la suma, y luego compararlo con el  mismo proceso pasado, de esa manera ya al dar el menor digito de la resta es por que es el mas cercano al valor y luego ya seria retornar, es asi?

Comment: o si me puedes decir que logica usaste me ayudarías a comprender mas jaja

Comment: Así es, de esa forma se puede buscar la diferencia mínima entre el valor deseado y la suma de los otros dos valores